# Ionic use cache to store data

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, caching, ionic4

I am new to ionic and wondered when to use cache and how.

I have serveral questions:

1. When it is recomended to use cache and when not at all?
2. What is the best way to implement cache?
3. Is there a size limit (in MB) of it?
4. Is there a different limit of size for each device?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**When to use the Native storage**

- Simple: Uniform and convenient way of organizing, storing, and accessing the data
- Fast: Less than 1 milisecond to save or retrieve an object (in general)
- Persistence: Save data over multiple sessions, i.e. holds the data till the application is removed from the device
- Small data: Store small amounts of persistent data (less than a few hundred kilobytes) It is possible to store more than a few megabytes, but that's not the intended usage of the plugin.

**Examples**

Storage of:

- User preferences
- Game progress
- Text
- ...

ref: https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

For storing many objects please consider trying a database-based strategy, for instance: WebSQL and SQLite plugin.